# Determinar o maior numero de uma coluna e exibir o nome em uma tabela do banco mysql?

Tags: python, sql, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela funcionario que utiliza varias redes de uma empresa. Preciso determinar qual a rede que o funcionario passou mais tempo logado dentro e 90 dias apartir de hoje.

```
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | matricula| rede       |
+------+----------+------------+
|    1 |   333    |        MAN |
|    2 |   333    |        MAN |
|    3 |   111    |       Test |
|    4 |   333    |        MAN |
|    5 |   111    |       Test |
|    6 |   333    |       Test |
|    7 |   333    |       Test |
+------+----------+------------+
```

Explicando melhor: Tenho de mostrar apos o select

```
333 MAN
111 Test
```

O programador tem de criar um select para determinar qual a rede que mais usou e mostra na saída.

**Código**

```
select 
    matricula, count(rede) as rede_bb 
from 
    ids_sti_tab_login
where
    data_inc  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY matricula
```

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho de mostrar o nome da REDE no select !!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Grato pelo ajudar. Falta apenas mostrarr o nome ao fim de select ! De que forma posso exibir o nome da maior rede utilizada ? @Motta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A minha solução:**

```
select 
    distinct(matricula), rede_bb, count(*) as quantidade 
from 
    ids_sti_tab_login 
where 
    data_inc  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW() 
group by 
    matricula, rede_bb order by quantidade desc;
```

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]